# Facebook graph api without making any fb app

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use facebook-api without making any facebook app, just from Graph api?
So that I can ask people to share there facebook profile information(public or non-public) with me given that they have control over whatever information they want to share. In graph-api, the only way I know, is to ask people to get a access token and give me.
I wanted it to be a system generated request for permission and all they had to do is just hit okay or hit cancel and depending that I get response related to access-token.
and To make a working facebook-app I atleast need to have a website or android app or something else, which I don't have it yet.
I can't think of any working way.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need Access Tokens for almost all API calls, and you can only get Access Tokens with an App - no matter which Access Token.

Comment: facebook-graph-api can do app part for me?

Comment: not sure what you mean. you just have to create an app to use the graph api.

Answer (score 0):

@luschn is right that you need Access Token to API Calls. You can easily create a new app using Facebook. Once you created an app, you can generate token, which can be used to make Graph API Calls.

**Helpful Links:**

App Create Link https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Get Token: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=comment&version=v2.11